# LinkedList issues

Tags: java, linked-list, iterator

I am trying to create a MyLinkedList class that is a singly linked, non-circular list where each node only has one link next and the list has a head and a tail link. The class is also supposed to implement an iterable interface. I am encountering an issue wherein addFirst and addEnd I get an error of cannot find symbol - variable list. I don't know why this error is occurring as this layout worked for ArrayLists.

```
 public class MyLinkedList<E extends Comparable<E>> extends LinkedList implements Iterable
    {
        public  void main(String args[]){
            LinkedList<E> list = new LinkedList<E>();
        }
        
        public Iterator iterator(){
            
             
            
        }
        
        public void addFirst(E value){
            list.addFirst(value);
        }
        
        public void addEnd(E value){
            list.add(value);
        }
    }
```

Comment: `list` is only defined in the `main`.

Comment: Isn't it cheating to use existing `LinkedList` as an implementation?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you you try to implement a wrapper for a `LinkedList<E> list` which should be a field in your class and delegate calls to this field.

```java
public class MyLinkedList<E extends Comparable<E>> extends LinkedList implements Iterable {
    private LinkedList<E> list = new LinkedList<>();

    @Override  
    public Iterator iterator() {       
        return list.iterator();       
    }
        
    public void addFirst(E value) {
        list.addFirst(value);
    }
        
    public void addEnd(E value) {
        list.add(value);
    }
}
```